# how do i run 'image-webpack-loader' webpack in production mode only?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Version: webpack 3.5.5
when i run the `webpack -d --watch` in terminal..

It just so slow to run the build ... Total Time: 174094ms

I install the image-webpack-loader in my webpack to compress my png images file..

but everytime run the `webpack -d --watch` in development mode.. it always compress again.. how do i run once only for the loader when in development...

I want run the compress loader when i run  `webpack -p` to build production code

here is my webpack config file:

```js
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './public/js/app.js',
    watchOptions: {
        poll: true
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js/',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                      presets: ['es2015']     
                    }
                  }
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'file-loader',
                      options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: '../font/'
                      }  
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/i, 
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'file-loader',
                      options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: '../img/compress/'
                      }  
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                          optipng: {
                            optimizationLevel: 7,
                          },
                          pngquant: {
                            quality: '65-90',
                            speed: 4
                          }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {                
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: "style-loader", 
                        use: "css-loader" 
                    }
                )            
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: false,
            mangle: false,
            minimize: true,
            compress: true
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "../css/app.bundle.css"
        })
        
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is outdated, but I still want to answer it for future visitors.

You can add the `bypassOnDebug` option to your loader, as shown below. This ensures that compression is 'bypassed' during development and only executed during production. This will greatly enhance your builds during development mode!

```
loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
         options: {
           bypassOnDebug: true,
         }
```

For more information, you can visit https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader#usage